# eth0 changed to eno1 and 70-persistent-net.rules is missing

Tags: 14.04, networking, dhcp, interface

I booted up Ubuntu, noticed I had no internet.  Ran ifconfig, eth0 is now eno1 and has no IP.  I ran dhclient eno1, no DHCP server found.  Went to check 70-persistent-net.rules, it's gone.  I rebooted and tried to regenerate it, no luck.  I am kind of a linux noob and this problem is driving me crazy.

oh, and /etc/network/interfaces only has lo, no other interfaces listed.

I haven't pasted any command outputs because as I said, no internet.  If need be I will manually type out terminal outputs, but I don't want to have to do excessive typing.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE: WiFi is working now, although it cuts out every 10-15min and the interface has the be brought down and up to reconnect.

Comment: Have you done any significant changes lately? Maybe a strange command? You could try add two lines to /etc/network/interfaces: `allow-hotplug eno1` and `iface eno1 inet dhcp`, then run `sudo ifup eno1` and see if you have connection.

Comment: The stranges thing I've done is do some GRUB changes, but that wouldn't affect this would it?

Comment: GRUB could actually affect it, depending on the settings you made. For example, if you pointed GRUB to a different kernel or appended some boot parameters to your kernel.

Comment: I might of done that...  I installed Kali on a another hard drive in the same machine, and it wanted to overwrite the GRUB, but instead a made it install it's own disk, so I could use it in another computer.

Comment: Revert GRUB settings to default and see if that works.

Comment: I reinstalled and updated grub, problem persists

Comment: Same problem in one of the computers in my office. Also looking for a solution (as well as the causes of the issue).

Comment: Possible solution (Ubuntu 15.10) found [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/689143)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

You'll see something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Add eno1:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: this probably isn't the right way to go about it though, since NetworkManager will not manage interfaces specified here, and we want NetworkManager to manage our interfaces in general... was that all you had to do?