# Wired connection not working after recovery

Tags: networking, 15.10, ethernet, wired

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and encountered some issues with wired connection.
after using grub, using Ubuntu recovery option with networking enabled it messed up my wired connection settings.

using:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

returns:

```
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

using:

```
dmesg | grep eth
```

returns:

```
[ 2.073397] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[ 2.215551] r8152 2-1:1.0 eth0: v1.08.1 (2015/07/28)
[ 3.237153] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx9cebe8261253: renamed from eth0
[ 69.963790] r8152 2-1:1.0 eth0: v1.08.1 (2015/07/28)
[ 71.017553] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx9cebe8261253: renamed from eth0
[ 195.797143] r8152 2-1:1.0 eth0: v1.08.1 (2015/07/28)
[ 196.861909] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx9cebe8261253: renamed from eth0
[ 229.932958] r8152 2-1:1.0 eth0: v1.08.1 (2015/07/28)
[ 230.981139] r8152 2-1:1.0 enx9cebe8261253: renamed from eth0
```

Wireless connection still works fine. I'm using laptop (Asus UX305FA), so my wired connection is though usb to ethernet adapter.
Wired connection worked out of the box with adapter on fresh install.
I would appreciate any help I could get on how to resolve this issue.

### Edit:

```
ip link
```

returns:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 5c:e0:c5:1b:e0:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enx9cebe8261253: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 9c:eb:e8:26:12:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Note that number 3 is missing I think number 3 used to be my original wired connection, but it's no longer recognized when I plug in my ethernet cable.

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules
```

There is no such file, do I create a new file with line?

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="10:c3:7b:4e:1d:6a″,KERNEL=="enp3s0″, NAME="eth0″
```

### Edit2:

```
ifconfig enx9cebe8261253
```

returns:

```
enx9cebe8261253 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:eb:e8:26:12:53  
                inet addr:10.250.29.214  Bcast:10.250.29.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
                inet6 addr: fe80::9eeb:e8ff:fe26:1253/64 Scope:Link
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
                RX bytes:3866 (3.8 KB)  TX bytes:18573 (18.5 KB)
```

and wifi

```
ifconfig wlp2s0
```

returns:

```
wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:e0:c5:1b:e0:bd  
          inet addr:192.168.43.247  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ee0:c5ff:fe1b:e0bd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:306366 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:427480060 (427.4 MB)  TX bytes:10062427 (10.0 MB)
```

Looks pretty much identical, but wireless works and wired does not

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ip link
```

My output:

```
alex@IT-CROWD:/etc/udev/rules.d$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:c3:7b:4e:1d:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And you can change the device name by defining the name manually with an udev-rule in(if file not existed create):

> /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules

Add the following line, and don't forget change MAC and KERNEL to your MAC and KERNEL:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="10:c3:7b:4e:1d:6a″,KERNEL=="enp3s0″, NAME="eth0″
```

These rules will be applied automatically at boot.

Comment: Yes, create new file but  add this:

`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="9c:eb:e8:26:12:53",KERNEL=="enx9cebe8261253", NAME="eth0"`

And reboot. If not work with NAME="eth0" try NAME="eth1"

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything tried both eth0 and eth1, the name still remains enx9cebe8261253 and wired connection doesn't work. I think the name might not be an issue, since i tried usb tethering and internet connection didn't work and it gave some random name as well. I m guessing enx9cebe8261253 is just an adapter name and its not working due to some other settings that are messed up.

Comment: This instruction renames enx9cebe8261253 to eth0 or eth1 for convenience.

But you may work with enx9cebe8261253, just use `ifconfig enx9cebe8261253 up`.  In general enx9cebe8261253 it eth0.

Look answer kyodake:
[link](http://askubuntu.com/a/689143/497827)