# Ubuntu 15 network naming issue

Tags: networking, 15.10, docker

Installing Ubuntu 15.10.
Qualcomm broadband onboard Ethernet is being renamed to enp4s0 from eth0.
I am.aboutnto get my onboard wifi to work but when I switch to use my wired connection I get nothing.

In a perfect world I would like to be able to rename my connection to eth0 as I am using docker and the automatic bridge looks for eth0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network interface name changes after update to 15.10 - udev changes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my on-board network controller was known to be an issue with Ubuntu.
Lucky I am at work and not at home.
Switched out to a new computer and Ubunutu worked first install.

On-board Network controller was Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)