# Network interface down after every reboot in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, 15.10, ethernet

I have recently upgraded my ubuntu to 15.10 and eventually Ethernet names were changed. I don't have any problem with the names but whenever I reboot the system the Ethernet connectivity is lost. The problem is the that the Ethernet device doesn't come up itself so I have to manually run the command.

ip link set ens255f0 up.

In /etc/network/interfaces file, I put

auto ens255f0
iface ens255f0 inet dhcp

but it didn't help. Could anybody help how can I solve this problem?

P.S: This is not duplicate question to this as there is no mention of this issue.
[Network interface name changes after update to 15.10 - udev changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, just had the same problem myself, after install if you had no network plugged in it defaults the NIC to down after every restart.

/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml replace eno1 with NIC tag, for example: ens255f0

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

reboot after done, this fixed two servers I had installed OS off network.

Answer (score 0):

Edit rc.local file

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add below lines above exit 0:

```
ifdown ens255f0
sleep 3
ifup ens255f0
```

Reboot