# My Wifi Card is not called wlan0 but wlp18s0b1, how then to configure my Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, essid

after some serious digging I finally realised that the problem with setting up my Ubuntu server via wifi is not working because wlan0 is not configured but it turns out that wlp18s0b1 is!? When I run `iwconfig wlp18s0b1` I get the following:

```
IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:off/any
Mode: Managed Access Point: Not Associated Tx-Power=0 dBm
Retry short limit: 7 RTS thr: off Fragment thr: off
Encryption key: off
Power Management: on
```

How then can I set my ESSID?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network interface name changes after update to 15.10 - udev changes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you set up /etc/network/interfaces something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp18s0b1
iface wlp18s0b1 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here.

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlp18s0b1 && sudo ifup -v wlp18s0b1
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks this works but the problem I'm facing now is connecting to the server from outside the network. I think that main thing that fixed this was rebooting from USB booting software. Unetbootin apparently has know issues.