# how to change ens33 to eth in ubuntu 16 and enable ssh

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

I am using vmware and installed "ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64". It didn't ask any question it directly installed and shows the login terminal. after login I try to enable ssh, for that I checked

> ifconfig

it shows ens33 with some ip address , I used that for ssh, it not working.

and I searched how to change the ens33 to eth and found some links.

They ask me to change the grub file. I did. no use. please help me on this issue.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the interface name in order to enable ssh?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes

Comment: @steeldriver, I don't know how to connect with ens33, I tried that IP it fails. Please give me some tutorial link for that.

Comment: @ThatGuy, I tried all of that , no luck for me.