# eth0 ERROR while getting interface flags: no such device

Tags: networking

I had opened a terminal to install `macchanger` via `sudo apt-get install -y macchanger`, and then entered my password. It stated that `macchanger` was already the newest version, so I typed `clear` and then ran:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

which is when this error message appeared:

```
eth0 ERROR while getting interface flags: no such device
```

This is a laptop and I am connected via ethernet cable.

How can I resolve this, so that I can run `macchanger`?

---

So I used `ifconfig -a` and I'm looking but seeing no mention of
 `eth0`

The interfaces that are showing top to bottom are:

```
enp58s0f1
lo
tun0
UNSPEC
wlp59s0
```

The only reference to ethernet is the MAC and also `txqueuelen`

Does this help in figuring what I need to do to get this sorted?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain where you see this message, what your hardware is, if this is a wired or wireless connection, what *exact* command you ran.

Comment: Run `ifconfig -a` - is it really named `eth0`?

Comment: @waltinator You should make an answer about the change of naming convention in systemd

Comment: @chaskes [https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes)

Comment: `enp58s0f1` (rather than `eth0`) is your Ethernet.

Comment: That is so helpful! Really appreciate your explanation, which has made a Noob2Ubuntu very happy.

Answer (score 11):

According to your `ifconfig -a` output, `enp58s0f1` is your Ethernet, not `eth0`.

When Ubuntu switched to systemd (at Ubuntu 15.04), it switched away from the old system with `eth0` and so on to what are called [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). Ethernet interfaces start with `en` (so yours is `enp58s0f1`). Wireless interfaces start with `wl`.

Comment: That is so helpful! Really appreciate your explanation, which has made a Noob2Ubuntu very happy.

Comment: Nice of them to make explanatory error messages...  :|

Answer (score 1):

First, read the manual.

```
man ifconfig
```

Then, afterwards, you'll understand what ifconfig does. also, ifconfig is considered to be a deprecated tool (i still use it however, it's handy because it's familiar and easy to use).

```
ifconfig -a
```

Will display all interfaces.

```
ip address # will also display similar information.
```

You might want to do some googling on some basic networking commands and how they work. [TLPD](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/c8319.htm) has a quick synopsis on some of the most common commands in linux for networking.

My arch system is configured to give older interface names, but the newer names (automatically configured by ubuntu) give newer (more complicated, harder to remember, and type) information.

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.254.3/24 brd 192.168.254.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 82688sec preferred_lft 82688sec
    inet6 f::f:f:f:f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You can see I have 3 interfaces, `lo` (for loopback), `eth0` (for ethernet), and `wlan0` (for wireless). If you don't use the correct interface name, then it won't work.

The following command will bring the interface up if it was down. The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/networking.html) has some detailed information on how to accomplish configuration, bringing the interface down, and back up.

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Answer (score -1):

Network interfaces may have other names, since the renaming mode is enabled when 1-2 digits are partially taken from the `pci number` of the network device to generate a specific name. This is done so that the names of network devices are not connected to the machine by new adapters. As a result, eth0 can be called, for example, enp2s1 or ens1, or even eng78e7d1er12ds

To disable renaming:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Replace the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0"
```

Then update GRUB with:

```
sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
```

Check your current settings:

```
ifconfig
```

As a result, I get (depending on the number of your installed network cards):

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:w0:4c:u6:97:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::c93e:6718:72e9:4423  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0a:5r:c2:21:70  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 376  bytes 467372 (467.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 398  bytes 41048 (41.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 137  bytes 11110 (11.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 137  bytes 11110 (11.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```