# Tasksel removed everything in my Ubuntu - how can I recover it?

Tags: tasksel

I accidentally removed Lubuntu in tasksel. How do I recover it through login shell?

My problem is I can't connect to a network to be able to download the Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I tried hat one but no luck.. My problem is that I cant connect to network to install it

Comment: If you use ethernet with DHCP you can bring it up `sudo dhclient e` (click <Tab> to auto-complete). And then use `apt` command.

Comment: Ok thanks bro I tried to use ethernet and use sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and it started to download .. Do i need to use dhclient e what is it for?

Comment: My recommendation about `dhclient e` was for obtainining dynamic IP from DHCP server. "`e`" here is universal prefix for `eth0` (old naming) or `enp2s0` (new [naming](https://askubuntu.com/a/689143/66509)) of eth-devices. You do not need to use this command if `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` is running :)

Comment: Probably faster to simply reinstall